# How to send multiple mime parts in body with feign

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

My code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/upload",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
String upload(@RequestHeader(AUTH_TOKEN) String bearerToken,
              @RequestHeader("X-Requested-By") String reqBy,
              @RequestPart("a") MultipartFile attributes,
              @RequestPart("f") MultipartFile file);
```

The `attributes` MultiPartFile has the content type `application/json`, the `file` is `text/plain`.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Scope("prototype")
public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
    return new SpringFormEncoder();
}

@Bean
feign.Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return feign.Logger.Level.FULL;
}

@Bean
public Encoder multipartFormEncoder() {
    return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(new ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters>() {
        @Override
        public HttpMessageConverters getObject() throws BeansException {
            return new HttpMessageConverters(new RestTemplate().getMessageConverters());
        }
    }));
}
```

Pom.xml contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-form-spring</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These are logs:

```
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [ActionResult [success=false, errorMsg=, data=null]]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to FileOperationController#upload(MultipartFile, List)
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/manager/upload", parameters={multipart}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to FileOperationController#upload(MultipartFile, List)
o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments: [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@3435e994, [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@3af20162]]
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] ---> POST https://example.com:8443/upload HTTP/1.1
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] Accept: text/plain
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] Authorization: Bearer eyJgIw
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] Content-Length: 762
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=18973c0df55
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] X-Requested-By: User
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] 
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] Binary data
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] ---> END HTTP (762-byte body)
.b.s.l.c.f.ServiceFeignClient : [ServiceFeignClient#upload] <--- HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable (368ms)
```

This is what I want to send:

```
------1890be27dba
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

 

{"values":["test123"]}
------1890be27dba
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type:text/plain

 

test
------1890be27dba--
```

The log does not contain two mime types, but some binary data without the boundary. Where is the problem? Thanks.